# ASP.NET form project two projects in one solution and one aspx page refers aspx page in anther project

Tags: asp.net

I am working on upgrade to 4.5 .net frame work and found the 10 year old code that I have never seen before.

This ASP.net form project has two project, both can be hosted.
One aspx page has a image button, and I check the code

aspx page in project A
  xxx.Attributes.Remove("src")
  xxx.Attributes.Add("src", "../xfolder/y.aspx")

y.aspx aspx page is in project B

My question is how can project A  and project B hosted? They hosted on the same web site on IIS? Or just create a sub folder under the main folder, so when ever y.aspx called it will be found.

Hope my question makes sense.

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 0):

You can host them under the same site in IIS but one would need to be a virtual site of the other i.e. www.sitea.com and www.sitea.com/siteb.